# Regex match only working with first catches (JavaScript)

Tags: regex

I have a file content into memory. Within the file, there are variables with the form of:

```
{{ _("variable1") }}
{{ _("variable2") }}
{{ _("variable3") }}
```

I'm trying to catch them with `/\{\{ _(.+) \}\}/i`:

```
var result = /\{\{ _(.+) \}\}/i.exec(fileContents);
```

It seems to work at first, as the first two variables are pushed into the array, but then it pushes the whole file content.

What am I missing?

**BONUS:** It would be awesome if I could grab **variable1** instead of **{{ _("variable1") }}** but I can live with it.

Comment: Just try adding the `g` modifier to your regex. If you then also add `\("` and `"\)` around `(.+)`, that should solve both problems.

Comment: It only catches **{{ _("Home") }} | {{ _("PikaPay") }}** as a whole

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid you'd have multiple ones on a single line. That changes a lot in your case. See my answer below. The problem is `.+` being greedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the `g` flag. This way you get an additional match every time you call `exec` (until there are no further matches, and you get `null`). For the bonus, just include the `("` and `")` in the pattern, so that they are not captured. Finally, you might want to make the `.+` ungreedy, otherwise you'll get funny surprises if there are multiple occurrences of this pattern in a single line:

```
r = /\{\{ _\("(.+?)"\) \}\}/ig;
while(m = r.exec(fileContents)
{
    // m[0] will contain the entire match
    // m[1] will contain the contents of the quotes
}
```

By the way, if `"variable1"` cannot contain escaped quotes (like `"some\"oddvariable"`), then this regex should be slightly more efficient:

```
r = /\{\{ _\("([^"]*)"\) \}\}/ig
```